# Projection onto manifold of Gaussian measures by "trunction" of moments

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-probability

Let $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the set of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite mean and variance; in the sense that
$$
\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \|x\|^p d\mathbb{P}(x) < \infty,
$$
for $p=1,2$.  Let $\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the set of Gaussian measures thereon (possibly degenerated).

Does there exist a metric $d$ on $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that the metric projection
$$
\inf_{\mathbb{Q}\in \mathcal{G}(\mathbb{R}^n)} d(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{P})
$$
is given by the Gaussian measure $\hat{P}$ with mean
$$
(\mu_{\mathbb{P}})_i=\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} x_i d\mathbb{P}(x)
$$ and covariance
$$
\left(\Sigma_{\mathbb{P}}\right)_{i,j}\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} 
\left[
x_i - (\mu_{\mathbb{P}})_i
\right]
\left[
x_j - (\mu_{\mathbb{P}})_j
\right]
\mu_{\mathbb{P}};
$$
here $i,j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a metric is given by
$$d(P,Q):=2\times1\{(\mu_P,\Sigma_P)\ne(\mu_Q,\Sigma_Q)\}+\sup_B|P(B)-Q(B)|$$
for Borel probability measures $P$ and $Q$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite second moments, where the $\sup$ is taken over all  Borel subsets $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: we could have replaced the second term with the Wasserstein-2 distance for example (I guess); right?

Also, is there literature on this object; that is, is it studied/named etc...?  Also,

Comment: @Elbebe : Yes, the second term can be replaced by any metric whose values are $<2$. Unfortunately, I don't know any literature on this.

Comment: That's alright.  That's the best 2-fold answer possible.  Thanks Iosif